# SQL Command Not Properly Ended for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute-immediate

I am trying to write a script that will end sessions. I get the SQL command not properly ended when trying to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong and why I am getting the error message. I have removed the ; form the line cur_show_connection and that didn't work as well.

```
|| ''' IMMEDIATE' sqlstatement
```

Here is my full code

```
declare
   cursor cur_show_connections is
     SELECT    'ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION '''
               || SID
               || ','
               || SERIAL#
               || ''' IMMEDIATE;' sqlstatement
     FROM v$session
     WHERE machine = 'XXXXX';

     sqlstr varchar2(3200) :='';

begin

    for rec_show_connections in cur_show_connections loop

       sqlstr := sqlstr || rec_show_connections.sqlstatement || chr(13) || chr(10);
      --Tried here and this didnt work either 
      --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr;
    
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlstr);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr;
    
    --This seems to work hardcoding the values
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION '425,7516' IMMEDIATE]';

end;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't end your `ALTER SYSTEM` command with a semi-colon. The `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command will take care of that.

```
cursor cur_show_connections is
     SELECT    'ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION '''
               || SID
               || ','
               || SERIAL#
               || ''' IMMEDIATE' sqlstatement
     FROM v$session
     WHERE machine = 'XXXXX';
```

You're also concatenating your commands into a single EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement. That won't work the way you're doing it: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE can only run one command or PL/SQL block at a time.

```
for rec_show_connections in cur_show_connections loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec_show_connections.sqlstatement);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE rec_show_connections.sqlstatement;
end loop;
```

OR

```
sqlstr = 'BEGIN ';

for rec_show_connections in cur_show_connections loop
    sqlstr := sqlstr || dbms_output.put_line(rec_show_connections.sqlstatement) || '; ';
end loop;

sqlstr := sqlstr || ' END;'

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr;
```

Depending on how many sessions you might need to disconnect, the first option is less likely to have issues with character string size limitations. PL/SQL has a 32K limitation that could affect how big a single PL/SQL concatenated block could get, potentially throwing an error if you tried to kill too many sessions at once.

Comment: Hi thanks, I did remove the semi colon from the cursor, but that didn't work for me

Comment: Updated my answer: you're also concatenating the commands into a single EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, which won't work either.

Comment: I’d say the reason it doesn’t accept a semicolon here is because it expects either a PL/SQL block or a SQL statement, and SQL doesn’t have semicolons.